# Where would I put something that would only ever run once?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I've got a C# website which includes a Master page.  So, when the user first opens the site, I want to run a script that tells me where the user lives.  I then will write that info to a hidden field, and any time I need to reference that information I will just pull it from this hidden field.

So, where would I put this reference in the code-behind, so that it's only ever run once?  I tried putting it in the `if (!IsPostBack)` inside of `protected void master_Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)` and that didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use session storage to detect if you have queried it yet, and to store it. You can do that on a page load

Comment: Why not just check the content of the field? Maybe, a session variable might be more appropriate.

Comment: You could store this as a cookie, assuming that people will be visiting the site multiple times

Comment: So how do I only run this session variable once?  And does it stay active the entire time the user is on the website?  There's multiple pages on this site, the reason I'm using a Master page is because there's a static menu, but each menu item sends the user to a different page.

Comment: You should probably read something about ASP.Net Session. And regarding the "only once": as I understand your question it is not really important to run only once, but its important to **check and use** if available and **compute if missing**

Comment: So when you say "only once", you mean "Once per user, per session", or "once per user"? I'd recommend setting a cookie for this purpose and only run that bit of code that does a location lookup if the cookie isn't present. You can call this method anywhere then (page_load of your master page for example). The benefit of using a cookie is the lookup will then survive server side session timeouts.

Comment: Just to check if you like this comment as others.

Answer (score 1):

Well, HiddenField isn't going to work for your requirements.

I recommend you pick your preferred persistence mechanism first.  Here is a great MSDN page that lists all the persistence mechanisms available in ASP.NET:

[ASP.NET State Management Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx)

This is a list of the mechanisms covered:

- View state
- Control state
- Hidden fields
- List item
- **Cookies**
- Query strings
- Application state
- **Session state**
- **Profile Properties**

Of these, based on what I know about your problem, I would recommend looking into Cookies, Session State, or Profile Properties.  These 3 mechanisms track data per user and can be persisted throughout your web application.

Read up on how to implement the mechanism of your choice, try some code out, and if you have further problems, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the values in Session_Start method in Global.asax page

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   setValue();
}

protected void setValue(){
  session["DefaultValue"]="test";
}
```

The Session_Start method will execute only once when session is created for the logged in user and then the value stored in the session will be accessible all over the application.

Comment: Based on the question been posted i guess this should be a working trick

Comment: Cookies could also be used, or user profiles if the site requires logins.

Comment: This is the common practice and usually followed, thats why Session_Start () is there @pseudocoder

Answer (score 0):

If u r accessing data from database, then u can retrieve data after login and store it in session.

If u r accessing data using Google map, then in Master page !Ispostback check for the data in session, if not found then run the script from client page store the value in hiddenfield. And after postback store the value of hidden field in session, If session data is null.